# How to create non-virtual folders in Visual Studio 2019 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm having an issue with virtual folders in Visual Studio while writing C++. Folders created via Solution Explorer are virtual therefore breaking my file loading and folders created outside it and included in project are not shown but files appears in a flat list.
Any idea how to force Visual Studio to always make non-virtual folders or just what's reasonable way to manage all that?

Comment: @drescherjm .cpp files created through dialog still make file show in virtual folder "Source Files" and still doesn't make real folder visible. My problems are mainly my resource files which just appears in flat list without showing real folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution Explorer has two modes

1. normal - displaying folder structure on disk as is
2. filter - "virtual" folders, defined in `*.vcxproj.filters` file

Corresponding toolbar button can be used to switch between them:
[image]

Comment: That's one of possible solutions indeed but showing all files not allow me for hiding specific folders like lib folders I'm linking and Debug/Release folders that is VS created. I'm wondering how to make it behave exactly like when writing in c#.

Comment: @ArcheRion "hiding specific folders like lib folders I'm linking and Debug/Release folders that is VS created" is whole different kind of problem. I'd say that typically lib and Debug/Release folders do not belong to solution folders. So i'm using out-of-source build in dedicated build cache folder on separate ssd and another dedicated folder to store build artifacts.